# Python - SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Tags: python

I want to read from a file the variables (they are links) and then open them with `urlopen` in a while loop so that every link is opened.

My code is:

```
   # Variables
   from config import *

   # Imports
   import urllib


   i = 0
   url = 100
   while i < 25:
       page = urllib.urlopen( url );
       page.close();
       i = i + 1
       url = 100
       url = url + i
```

The error i get is `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`. I kind of understand why, but i don't know how to bypass it!

`config.py`

```
100 = 'https:link'
101 = 'https:link'
102 = 'https:link'
```

Comment: Your problem is in `config.py` (or some transitive inclusion). Most likely something like `42 = answer`.

Comment: i've updated with the config file, but i don't uderstand what you mean!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what the error is. You can't assign to a literal. `100` is a literal because it *literally* has the value 100. Your config.py is trying to change the value of the integer `100`.

If you're trying to iterate over a list of variables or values starting with 100, one solution would be to create a dictionary and use the numbers for the keys. For example:

```
# config.py
urls = {
    100: "https:link",
    101: "https:link",
    102: "https:link"
}
```

Then, in your code you can do something like this:

```
i = 0
while i < 25:
    url_number = 100 + i
    page = urllib.urlopen( urls[url_number] );
```

Comment: But that is what i want to do :D, so how do i need to do it then? PS. I'm a noob in python and every other programming languages, i just have some general knowledge !

Comment: Totally offtopic: [how to change the value of numbers in CPython](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28851/1688). Do not try at home :)

Comment: thanks! This is grate